# Trying to edit row in a gridview (C# ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to modify each row of a gridview, this is my first time programming in C# and using ASP.NET MVC

This is the way i chose to obtain to fetch the data from the database (this is my **Index.cshtml**):

```
@{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Display Data";
     string[] TableHeaders = new string[] {"Address ID"
                         ,"Address Line"
                         ,"City"
                         ,"State Province ID"
                         ,"Postal Code"
                         ,"Spatial Location"
                         ,"Row ID"
                         ,"Modified Date"}; }
 
 <div class="table">
     <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                 @{
                     foreach (var head in TableHeaders)
                     {
                         <th>
                             @head
                         </th>
                     }
                 }
             </tr>
         </thead>
 
         <tbody>
             @{
                 if (Model != null)
                 {
                     foreach (var Data in Model)
                     {
                         <tr>
                             <td>@Data.AddressID</td>
                             <td>@Data.AddressLine</td>
                             <td>@Data.City</td>
                             <td>@Data.StateProvinceID</td>
                             <td>@Data.PostalCode</td>
                             <td>@Data.SpatialLocation</td>
                             <td>@Data.RowID</td>
                             <td>@Data.ModifiedDate</td>
                         </tr>
                     }
                 }
             }
         </tbody>
     </table> </div>
```

I wanted to add a button in order to be able to modify each row, i added this:

```
<td>button value="EDIT" type="button" format class="btn btn-primary btn-edit">EDIT</button></td>
```

but i don't understand how can i obtain the id of each row and edit the content, i'm super lost.

---

EDIT #1

This is my Address.cs file (inside MODELS folder:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Data_Grid.Models
{
    public class Address
    {
        public string AddressID { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string StateProvinceID { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string SpatialLocation { get; set; }
        public string RowID { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my HomeController file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Data_Grid.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace Data_Grid.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            con.ConnectionString = Data_Grid.Properties.Resources.ConnectionString;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            FetchData();
            return View(addresses);
        }
        private void FetchData()
        {
            if(addresses.Count > 0)
            {
                addresses.Clear();
            }
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                com.Connection = con;
                com.CommandText = "SELECT TOP (1000) [AddressID],[AddressLine1],[City],[StateProvinceID],[PostalCode],[SpatialLocation],[rowguid],[ModifiedDate] FROM [AdventureWorks2019].[Person].[Address]";
                dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    addresses.Add(new Address() {AddressID = dr["AddressID"].ToString()
                    ,AddressLine = dr["AddressLine1"].ToString()
                    ,City = dr["City"].ToString()
                    ,StateProvinceID = dr["StateProvinceID"].ToString()
                    ,PostalCode = dr["PostalCode"].ToString()
                    ,SpatialLocation = dr["SpatialLocation"].ToString()
                    ,RowID = dr["rowguid"].ToString()
                    ,ModifiedDate = dr["ModifiedDate"].ToString()
                    });
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the Index view page(Index.cshtml), if you want to use the `<button>` tag, you could use the following code to add the id parameter to the button: `<td><form asp-action="Edit" method="post" asp-route-id="@Data.AddressID"><button>EDIT</button></form></td>` (when using this code, the route pattern like this: `pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");`, you could check it from the Startup.cs file). Then, after clicking the button, it will redirect to the Edit action method in the Home controller, so, try to add an Edit action and create the View first.

Comment: Here are some related tutorials about Asp.net Core CRUD Operations, you could refer to them: [Tutorial: Implement CRUD Functionality - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [ASP.NET CORE - Learn CRUD Operations In Entity Framework Core From Zero To Hero](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-learn-crud-operations-in-entity-framework-core-from-zero-to-hero/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have get and post methods in your HomeController class like this.

```
public ActionResult UpdateAddress(int id)
{

    var _addresses = new List<Address>
    {
        new Address {AddressID = 1, AddressLine = "AddressLine1", City = "City1"},
        new Address {AddressID = 2, AddressLine = "AddressLine2", City = "City2"},
        new Address {AddressID = 3, AddressLine = "AddressLine3", City = "City3"},
    };


    // Get the address by id
    var address = _addresses.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AddressID == id);



    return View(address);
}

[HttpPost]
public string UpdateAddress(Address address)
{


    return "Updated";
}
```

Add action links at the end of the TD tags. Like this.

```
<tr>
    <td>@Data.AddressID</td>
    <td>@Data.AddressLine</td>
    <td>@Data.City</td>
    <td>@Data.StateProvinceID</td>
    <td>@Data.PostalCode</td>
    <td>@Data.SpatialLocation</td>
    <td>@Data.RowID</td>
    <td>@Data.ModifiedDate</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UpdateAddress","Home", new { id = Data.AddressID },new {@class = "btn btn-primary btn-edit" })</td>
</tr>
```

The form on the address update page should be something like this.

```
@model Address

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateAddress", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.AddressID)
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AddressLine)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.AddressLine, "AddressLine")
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.City)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.City, "City")
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

When You click the Submit button, sends the address object to the post method of UpdateAddress Action.

Comment: Hey pal, how are you?
I'm checking it out!

Comment: Pal, i don get this: What are you trying to do in here:
    {
        new Address {AddressID = 1, AddressLine = "AddressLine1", City = "City1"},
        new Address {AddressID = 2, AddressLine = "AddressLine2", City = "City2"},
        new Address {AddressID = 3, AddressLine = "AddressLine3", City = "City3"},
    };

Comment: I wrote it just to be an example. You need to delete it and edit the that code: var address = _addresses.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AddressID == id); Get the address by id from the place where your addresses are registered (database, etc.).

Comment: I just updated my thread. How would you change it?. I'm kinda lost right.